# How to add Java Exception Site List for all users

Tags: windows-7, security, java, java-applet, java-web-start

I need to use an old Java applet for a certain website, but newer Java versions cannot run it, as it has a self-signed certificate. Reading on Oracle's Deployment Guide, I need to make my own deployment .JAR, with a proper certificate signing (not self signed), just to create the exception I need to run applets from a single domain.

I have found that there is a `%userprofile%\appdata\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites` file, obviously one for each user. In there, one per line, is a list of domains I can set to exclude from NOT being executed. When I add the domain name, the user gets a single prompt, then it just allows that domain for that user. Great.

I know I could add this file to the **Default** user profile, for any new users being created. Unfortunately, I do not think that removing every user's profile from each of the systems is the right way to go. I can push commands to computers, but the commands run as my user - I can't use %USERPROFILE% for this. I do not want to put it in my login script, as I do not want the file getting large for users who constantly log in and off of systems. I also only want the single domain *added* to whatever is there, without wiping out the user's preferences that may already exist.

Because I do not want to wipe out their preferences, I thought of doing something along the lines of `echo http://www.example.com >> %userprofile%\appdata\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites`, but that won't work, as it will keep adding to the file.

What can I do to add the list to the Exceptions rule, but only if the rule does not exist already?

Comment: ( I am wondering why this was migrated from serverfault ).  This is clearly meant for system administrators.

Comment: @Ramhound Wasn't getting views, and can still be useful here. I requested the migration, and I will fix it up to be on topic here

Comment: Alright, well that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure about how Java deals with it right now but if you look at the [Documentation for the Deployment configuration file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/properties.html) that there is a trusted cert store. It could be worth it to try to add the cert to that and it would be on a system level.

Comment: Gotta love that it has over 10k views, only 2 up votes max....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the following files to `C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment` folder.

**deployment.properties:**

```
deployment.user.security.exception.sites=C:/Windows/Sun/Java/Deployment/exception.sites
deployment.system.config.mandatory=True
```

**deployment.config:**

```
deployment.system.config=file:///C:/Windows/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties
deployment.system.config.mandatory=True
```

**exception.sites:**

```
http://some.trusted.site/
https://another.trusted.site/
```

This would affect all users of this machine.

Via:

- [Java 7u51 – System Wide Exception Site List an article posted on Systemsynergy](http://systemcentersynergy.com/java-7u51-system-wide-exception-site-list/)
- [Oracle Java SE Documentation - Deployment Configuration File and Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/properties.html)
- [Oracle Java SE Documentation - Exception Site List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/exception_site_list.html)

Comment: Java no longer placed the config files in these locations in newer versions of Windows, or newer versions of Java.

Comment: But Java applets are no more relevant for newer versions of Java, Windows and browsers, I guess. )

Comment: Yes, they are. Sadly. I wish they weren't, but my org has a bunch of legacy apps still requiring the JRE on each client. And yes, we're paying Oracle for the privilege.

Answer (score -3):

The exceptions are store here, C:\Users{username}\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites
Populate your file with what you want to add, copy it to a file share and use a logon script to copy the file for each user. This will make it to where users will not be able to add new sites.

Source:  http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_28518522.html

Comment: Overwriting user preferences and denying users the ability to modify them is something the OP wants to avoid in the first place.